# How to draw a number line with arrows inside it

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows

I am having trouble using TiKz to draw a correct picture. Here is how I started it out:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{<}}},postaction={decorate}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% a straight line segment
\draw[latex-] (-2,0) -- (0,0);
\draw[->-=.3] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[->-=.6] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[-latex] (1,0) -- (2,0);
% the ticks and their labels
\foreach \x  in {-1,...,1}
  \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-1pt) node[below,fill=white] {\the\numexpr\x +1\relax};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But I want my picture to look like this:

[image]

How do I make the numbers appear correctly, and also make the curved arrows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% a straight line segment
\draw[latex-] (-2,0) -- (0,0);
\draw[->-=.3] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[->-=.6] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[-latex] (1,0) -- (2,0);
% the ticks and their labels
\foreach \x [count=\i start from 0] in {-1,...,1}
  \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-1pt) node[below,fill=white] (\i) {\x};

\draw[->] (2) to [out=-95, in=-85] (0);
\draw[<-] (.25mm,1mm) arc(-85:265:3mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs I've updated the answer. You just need `{\x}` as node contents. `\x` cannot be used as node names because they are considered real values, and I've used `\i` which is an integer. But there is no problem using in nodes contents.